# No matching function call with std::map within class template

Tags: c++

I'm using std::map as a protected member within a template class. One of the template parameters is used as the key and another as its value.
Within the move constructor I try to emplace a pair(key and value). This yield the following compile error: `no matching function for call 'std::pair<keyType, valueType>::pair(keyType, valueType)'`

İ have tried using alternatives methods for adding a std::pair to the map such as insert and operator[]. They yield different compile errors. However, it seems I'm missing something regarding the template.

Here are the snippets of the code that yield the error:

```
//template.tpp  
template <typename E, typename S, typename D>
class Base
{
public:
    Base(S&& state);
    Base(S&& state, D&& data);

protected:
    std::map<E,S> m_states;
    E m_current_state;
    D m_data;
};

template <typename E, typename S, typename D>
Base<E, S, D>::Base(S&& state) : m_current_state(state.identifier()) {
    m_states.emplace(std::make_pair(std::move(state.identifier()), std::move(state)));
}
...

//derived.h
template class Base<Status, State, Data>;

class Derived : public QObject, public Base<Status, State, Data>
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Derived::Derived(State&& state, QObject* parent = nullptr);
...
};

//derived.cpp
Derived::Derived(State&& state, QObject* parent) :
        Base<Status, State, Data>(std::move(state)), QObject(parent) {}
```

The class `State` is a derived class from a templated base class.

```
template <typename E, typename D>
class BaseState {
...
}

class State : public QObject, public BaseState<Status, Data>
{
     Q_OBJECT
...
}
```

The class `Status` is an enum

```
enum class Status : unsigned int {invalid, valid, error};
```

Why do I get the compile error:

```
no matching function for call 'std::pair<Status, State>::pair(Status, State)' 
return __pair_type(std::forward<_T1>(__x), std::forward<_T2>(__y));

stl_pair.h: template argument deduction/substitution failed: mismatched types 'std::tuple<_Tps ...>' and 'Status'
```

If I remove the `m_states.emplace(...` the code compiles. What am I missing here?

Comment: Are the headers `<map>` and `<utility>` both #included? And what happens if you omit the `make_pair` call and just use the two arguments directly (you shouldn't need the `make_pair` with `emplace` anyway).

Comment: BTW, it [works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c23e6a5852cfecd). Can you check how your code differs? A [mcve] would be ideal.

Comment: The headers map and utility are included. I do use cpp11. Your code has just a single translation unit, while I have at least 3.
Removing the make_pair from emplace yields the same error.

Comment: I can only see one translation unit in the question, though.

Comment: Your're right about the translation units, I'll try to recreate the same issue with fewer lines of code.